# Javascript alert if bootstrap popover is null

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am building a form for a rail yard audit. This involves a bootstrap popover which contains a textarea in which the auditor can add comments. The popover is activated when a html checkbox is checked. All of this works fine, but now the end user wants an alert if the checkbox is checked and there are no comments in the popover text area. In most instances I have created a javascript variable that grabs the info from the form and then either alerts the end user to correct an error or submits the form if everything checks out.

```
<!doctype html>

            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />


            </head>
            <body>
            <FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="mainForm" onsubmit="return checkform()" action='process_rail_tally_form.php' style='max-width: 125em; min-width: 125em;'>



            <script>
            function checkform() {

            var zz = document.forms["mainForm"]["exempt"].value;
            var zy = document.forms["mainForm"]["exempt_com"].value;


            if ((zz.checked) && (zy == null || zy == "")) {
            alert("You have checked handling changed with rep present. Please enter some comments.")

            }

            else {

            alert("Thank You! To continue submitting your form click leave this page.");
            return true;
            }
            }
            </script>
            <table width='50%' align='center' BORDER='0' bordercolor='lightgray' CELLPADDING='0' CELLSPACING='0' STYLE='font-family: tahoma; font-size: 8pt; padding-left:10px; padding-right:0px;'>
            <script type="application/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#C1').change(function() {
            if($(this).val()=="OTHER"){
            $( "#comment1" ).hide();


                }
            if($(this).val()!="OTHER"){
            $( "#comment1" ).show();
                }
                });
            $("#Show_Upload").click(function(){
            $("#div-box").toggle();
                });
            $('#fadeslow').fadeIn('slow');
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
                html: true,
                });

                });
            </script>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <a href='#'  role='button' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='click' data-content="<textarea maxlength='2000' name='exempt_com'  rows='5' cols='40'></textarea>" title='Comments' style="font-size:8pt; !important;"><input name="exempt" type="checkbox"></input></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>      
            <center><input type="submit" style="color: black; font-size: 12pt" name="submit" value="Submit"/></center>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Forgot to ask a question: When I try to validate the checkbox is checked and there is no text in the popover the Javascript breaks. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should edit your question and add that there. Then it can't vanish in the comments.